# why can't I take the mean using np.mean()

Tags: python, numpy

I'm getting a key error: 'price'. . I scraped this website and took the prices of ps4 games. Im trying to take the mean price of the price column using np.mean() and passing the price variable a argument but I keep getting the key error 'price'. Any hints on how to clear the data so this won't happen?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
import re

url='https://www.newegg.com/PS4-Video-Games/SubCategory/ID-3141'

with uReq(url) as uClient:
    page = uClient.read()

# parsing
page_soup = soup(page, "html.parser")

# grabs products
containers= page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item-container"})

# file
filename = "products.csv"

d = defaultdict(list)
d1 = defaultdict(list)

# fill dict
for container in containers:
    brand = container.div.div.a.img["title"]

    title = container.findAll("a", {"class":"item-title"})
    product_name = title[0].text

    shipping_container = container.findAll("li", {"class":"price-ship"})
    shipping = shipping_container[0].text.strip()
    
    #price column
    pricec = container.find("li", {"class":"price-current"})
    #removing all white spaces
    price= pricec.text.strip('price-current')
    
    d['Product'].append(product_name)
    d['shipping'].append(shipping)
    d1['Product'].append(product_name)
    d1['Brand'].append(brand)
    d1['price'].append(price)
    
    
# create dataframe    
df = pd.DataFrame(d) #product and shipping
df1 =pd.DataFrame(d1) #product and brand 



# clean shipping column
df['shipping'] = df['shipping'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == 'Free Shipping' else x)
#string converted to float
df['shipping'] = df['shipping'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == 'Special Shipping' else x) # probably should be handled in a special way
df['shipping'] = df['shipping'].apply(lambda x: x if x == 0 else re.sub("[^0-9]", "", x))
df['shipping'] = df['shipping'].astype(float)

# save dataframe to csv file
df.to_csv('dataframe.csv', index=False)
df1.to_csv('dataframe1.csv', index=False)

# shipping filter 
#print(df[df['shipping'] > 5.99])

meanPrice= np.mean(price)
print(meanPrice)
```

Comment: `price` is jump some temporary variable you created during the for loop to hold the price. The actual list of prices you want to calculate the mean of is in `d1['price']`. Even then, you have to make sure to put `float`s in this list rather than strings, because the `mean` operation doesn't know how to calculate a mean of a list of strings.

Comment: thanks. any hints on how to keep only the numbers and take out the rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as @Trion said, you need to convert your price column from strings to float. We can do this with a regex expression. The change is two lines:

```
>>> df1['price'] = df1['price'].str.extract('(\d+\.?\d+)').astype(float)

>>> meanPrice= np.mean(df1['price'])

>>> print(meanPrice)
43.626216216216214
```

And this is the full code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
import re

url='https://www.newegg.com/PS4-Video-Games/SubCategory/ID-3141'

with uReq(url) as uClient:
    page = uClient.read()

# parsing
page_soup = soup(page, "html.parser")

# grabs products
containers= page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item-container"})

# file
filename = "products.csv"

d = defaultdict(list)
d1 = defaultdict(list)

# fill dict
for container in containers:
    brand = container.div.div.a.img["title"]

    title = container.findAll("a", {"class":"item-title"})
    product_name = title[0].text

    shipping_container = container.findAll("li", {"class":"price-ship"})
    shipping = shipping_container[0].text.strip()
    
    #price column
    pricec = container.find("li", {"class":"price-current"})
    #removing all white spaces
    price= pricec.text.strip('price-current')
    
    d['Product'].append(product_name)
    d['shipping'].append(shipping)
    d1['Product'].append(product_name)
    d1['Brand'].append(brand)
    d1['price'].append(price)
    
    
# create dataframe    
df = pd.DataFrame(d) #product and shipping
df1 =pd.DataFrame(d1) #product and brand 


# clean shipping column
df['shipping'] = df['shipping'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == 'Free Shipping' else x)
#string converted to float
df['shipping'] = df['shipping'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == 'Special Shipping' else x) # probably should be handled in a special way
df['shipping'] = df['shipping'].apply(lambda x: x if x == 0 else re.sub("[^0-9]", "", x))
df['shipping'] = df['shipping'].astype(float)

# save dataframe to csv file
df.to_csv('dataframe.csv', index=False)
df1.to_csv('dataframe1.csv', index=False)

# shipping filter 
#print(df[df['shipping'] > 5.99])
df1['price'] = df1['price'].str.extract('(\d+\.?\d+)').astype(float)

meanPrice= np.mean(df1['price'])
print(meanPrice)
```

Comment: @XavierValdez No worries. If you could accept my answer then the question will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

price contains a string it seems. np.mean operation needs to be on a numerical array.
So before writing the price, you should convert it into a number via int or float.

Comment: Recommendation: Perhaps complete the answer by showing an example of how this can be done.  Which, in this case, means deriving an example dataset for demonstration.